# Get list of months with posts

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-query

I am trying to add a filter on my custom theme based on post month, similar with the archives but with some differences.

What is the best way to get a list of months in witch we have posts?

Thanks,
Alex

I used the following query:

```
 $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS   `month`, count(ID) as posts 
                     FROM $wpdb->posts 
                     WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
                     GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC"
```

Could not use the `wp_get_archives` function because it returns only the following formats:

```
html - In HTML list (<li>) tags and before and after strings. This is the default.
option - In select (<select>) or dropdown option (<option>) tags.
link - Within link (<link>) tags.
custom - Custom list using the before and after strings.
```

Comment: If you can include some more details (such as code you're using or have tried, the specifics of what you're trying to do, and something that haven't worked), I suspect you'll get a much better answer. As it stands, it's hard to give you an specific-enough answer because it's not quite clear what you want.

Comment: I ended using the query mentioned above, not quite sure if a better way exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core can't help you here. You'll have to do a…

### Custom Query

Here's a save query, that I use on admin UI screens to get the total amounts of month with posts to use them in the custom pagination. Pay attention that I query not only for the published posts, but take into consideration that there might be some restriction set and apply it then.

```
$post_status = esc_attr( $_GET['post_status'] );
$post_status = in_array( $post_status, $GLOBALS['avail_post_stati'] )
    ? " AND post_status = {$post_status}"
    : 'all'
;
'all' === $post_status AND $post_status = '';

$total_page_dates = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT
        YEAR( post_date )  AS year,
        MONTH( post_date ) AS month,
        count( ID )        AS posts
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE
        post_type = %s
        %s
    GROUP BY
        YEAR( post_date ),
        MONTH( post_date )
    ORDER BY post_date
    ASC
", get_current_screen()->post_type, $post_status ) );
```

### Result

You'll then be able to inspect your result

```
// Inspect the result
var_dump( $total_page_dates );
```

Which might look like the following:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1847]
      public 'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
      public 'month' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'posts' => string '19' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[1846]
      public 'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
      public 'month' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'posts' => string '17' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[1845]
      public 'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
      public 'month' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'posts' => string '8' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[1844]
      public 'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
      public 'month' => string '9' (length=1)
      public 'posts' => string '2' (length=1)
```

You are then able to loop through it or simply grab the first or last array item to get the range. Counting - `count( $total_page_dates )` - would tell you how many month you got, etc. Keep in mind that every array value is an `object`, so you have to access it like this

```
$posts_in_first_month = total_page_dates[0]->posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [wp_get_archives()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

### Last Twelve Months

Displays archive list by month, displaying only the last twelve.

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=12'); ?>
```

### Last Fifteen Days

Displays archive list by date, displaying only the last fifteen days.

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=daily&limit=15'); ?>
```

### Last Twenty Posts

Displays archive list of the last twenty most recent posts listed by post title.

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&limit=20&format=custom'); ?>
```

**For a non-formatted solution, consider using [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Combining_Parameters)**

```
<?php 
    $allPosts = query_posts('cat=6&monthnum=04&year=2011');
    print_r($allPosts); 
?>
```

Comment: wp_get_archives returns a formated result, I only need the month and year value (01.2005, 02.2005 ...)

Comment: @thedev Updated my answer with an example using query_posts()

Comment: Thanks for your update, however I am not interested in the posts :) I am interested in the months that have posts.

Comment: Do NOT user `query_posts()`. Micheal, please revisit that answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that wp_get_archive is internally using for month archives

```
$query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts FROM $wpdb->posts $join $where GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date $order $limit";
```

and you are doing same thing, except that using distinct and group by together.